# Failed to extract manifest from APK: ProcessException: The command failed when trying to run flutter app on physical device

Tags: android-studio, flutter, debugging

'Launching lib\main.dart on Tecno V9 in debug mode...
Failed to extract manifest from APK: ProcessException: The command failed
Command: C:\Users\Veekvio\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.2\aapt dump xmltree
C:\Users\Veekvio\AndroidStudioProjects\i_am_rich\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_arm.
Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?'

Answer (score 1):

Delete the file

> build/app/outputs

And run command
`flutter create .`
And Re run the app